# This is the code for a serial adder of 6 bit numbers in VHDL.There is a compiling error " canot read output q",please help me out of this

Tags: vhdl

This is a code for two 6 bit serial adder.It acts like a scoreboard.iam getting a       compiling error " cannot read output q ".please help me out of this.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity board IS
port
(
C: in std_logic;
h : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
q : out std_logic_vector(5 downto 0)
-- s,cout : out std_logic
);
end board;

architecture archi of board is
signal tmp: std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
begin
process(C)
begin
  if(C'event and C='1') then
    tmp<= std_logic_vector (unsigned(q) + unsigned(h));
  end if;

end process;
q<=tmp;
end archi;
```

Comment: why does the title call it a serial adder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason (why?) you cannot read from output ports directly. Create an internal signal, e.g. `q_i`, replace all `q` by `q_i` and assign the internal signal to the output port, i.e. `q <= q_i`.

On a further note, your `tmp` signal is not necessary. You can write `q_i <= std_logic_vector((unsigned(q_i) + unsigned(h));` in a clocked process.

Comment: why?(a) ... because it's an OUTput port. Inside this unit you don't know what it'll resolve to : it may be shorted to "111111" outside this unit for all you know. Buffer would allow you to read the value regardless of external conditions. Or... Why?(b) Because you aren't using VHDL-2008. After 21 years of poor education about "buffer" the tools vendors gave up and added "buffer" syntax to "out" in VHDL-2008.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using numeric_std rather than std_logic_unsigned.  std_logic_unsigned is not an official ieee supported package.  At the top of your file do this and your problems should go away:

```
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
```

Also don't put signal h in your process sensitivity list.  That process is a clocked process and you shouldn't have any signal but your clock and an asynchronous reset in the sensitivity list (if you're using an async reset).  You don't need a reset at all here.